# How to make 1 div centre align and other float right using CSS

Tags: css

I want to make my div2 to centre align and div3 to be at right.

[image: What is expected]

I tried doing that with text align: center for main div and making float right to div3 but it is making it center align by considering main div's remaining part. I have given display: inline-flex to main div

[image: What is happening]

```html
<div style="height: 40px;width:120px;background-color: yellow;align-items: center;">

<div style="height: 20px;width:20px;background-color: red;">
  Hello
</div>

<div style="height: 20px;float: right;width:20px;background-color: red;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need code. Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: set width of div when you need in div  center

Comment: visit below code I answer yesterday.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450161/how-can-i-add-3-columns-in-an-html-page-using-css/43450339#43450339]

Comment: But is it OK if the two divs start overlapping on small screens? One of the strengths of floating is that it avoids overlap.

Answer (score 6):

Please try with this code:

```
<div style="height: 40px;width:120px;background-color: yellow;align-items: center; position:relative;">

<div style="height: 20px;width:40px;background-color: red; overflow:auto; margin:0 auto">
  Hello
</div>

<div style="height: 20px;position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px; width:20px;background-color: red;">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="margin: auto;"` to your div2 element. And 
`style="margin-left: auto;"` to your div3 element.

```html
<div style="height: 40px;width:120px;background-color: yellow;align-items: center;">

<div style="margin:auto; height: 20px;width:20px;background-color: red;">
  Hello
</div>

<div style="margin-left:auto; height: 20px;float: right;width:20px;background-color: red;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does work but it gives me result as in second image i attached. I want div 2 to consider width of main div and be align in center. Now it only consider width = main div - div3 and then get align to center which is not what is expected to happen.

Comment: I have edited the answer adding a code snippet. According to that what are the changes you need?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.main .div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.main .div2 {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div1">
    div1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    div2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Divs are block level elements, so you can use a margin of auto on the left and right to place it in the middle.

```
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

In the HTML you will need to adjust the ordering of the divs. Put div 3 before div 2 so that when you float it, they appear on the same line:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dcqpw12u/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:relative` for the main, and `position:absolute` to the other `div`, and it also centers it vertically

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.div3 {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div2">SOME DIV 2</div>
  <div class="div3">SOME DIV 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```css
.contentmain{
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
      color: black;
      height: auto;
      width: 35%;
      float: left;
      background:red;
  }
  .contentCenter{
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
      color: black;
      height: auto;
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      background:yellow;
  }
  .contentRight{
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
      color: black;
      height: auto;
      width: 35%;
      float: right;
      background:red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="contentmain">
  Main<br/>
  Content<br/>
 </div>
 <div class="contentCenter">
  Center<br/>
  Content<br/>
 </div>
 <div class="contentRight">
  Right<br/>
  Content<br/>
 </div>
```

This might be fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
.div0 {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: red;
  position: relative ;
}
.div1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  right: 0%;
  height: 40px;
  width:40px;
  border-color: green;
  position: absolute;
 }

 .div2 {
  left: 50%;
  right:50%;
  width:40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 40px;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: green;
    }
</style>            
</head>
<body>
<div class="div0">
  <div class="div1"><p>div1</p></div>
  <div class="div2"><p>div2</p></div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

basically you can achieve this by using the **position** property and the **right** and **left** properties of CSS which you can refer to more on 
[Position](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and  [right](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp) property left property could be found on the site.

what i've done in my answer is set the main div as position *relative* and the other sub divs(div2 and div3) as *absoulute*

To get one div to the right most corner you set the right property to 0%
and to center a div i used 50% on both right and left properties.